# Inkscape crops eps files generated with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, inkscape, eps

I have a script file to generate an eps file with gnuplot. The basics of this script are:

```
set terminal postcript enhanced color size 30,20 font 'Times-ew-Roman,40'
set xtics -.5,0.125
set ytics 0.1,0.1

set xrange [-0.5,.5]
set yrange [0.,1.6]
set cbrange [-0.5,.5]

set output "file.eps"
plot #whatever i plot
```

This script generates an eps file, which I can open in ubuntu and I can see is well printed. Now, I want to import this eps into inkscape, but when importing inkscape imports a big frame with only the top left drawn. The rest is blank. Do I have to change anyvalue in my gnuplot script or do something else with inkscape? I tried to open it in inskcape windows and ubuntu versions, and in both cases it happens the same with the same file.

Comment: if I reduce the 30,20 inkscape imports more image. It seems to be related to the size of the document...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you have not actually asked gnuplot to produce an eps image.  Instead you produced a generic PostScript document with a page size that does not match the default.   You need to put the keyword `"eps"` in your terminal command:

```
 set term postscript eps color size 30,20 font "Times-New-Roman,40"
```

Comment: Perfect! I only found the solution of changing the size of page, but with this trick is not necessary ;)